# Let $M = {\{x \in l^p : x(2n) = 0 \ \text{for all n}}\}$, $1 \le p \le \infty$. Show that $l^p/M$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, isometry

The following is Exercise 6 page 72 in Functional Analysis book of Conway :

> Let $M = {\{x \in l^p : x(2n) = 0 \ \text{for all n}}\}$, $1 \le p \le \infty$. Show that $l^p/M$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^p$.

First of all, am I right that I need to show three things to prove "isometrically isomorphism" : Surjection, Injection and Isometry?

1- Surjection : because the map is the canonical map so it surjection by definition.

2- Injection : I doubt that this is a 1-1 map unless we deter/adjust the definition of 1-1 here (?)

3- Roughly speaking $\inf_{m \in M} \sum_n |x_n|^p = \sum_n |x_n|^p$ because the zero sequence belongs to $M$ so it is isometry?

Comment: You may try $Tx=y$, where $y(n)=x(2n)$. $\|Tx\|_p\leq\|x\|_p$ and if $x\equiv y\operatorname{mod}M$ then $Tx=Ty$.

Comment: If $\pi:\ell_p\rightarrow \ell_p/M$ is the projection map, then there is a map $g:\ell_p/M\rightarrow \ell_p$ such that $T=g\circ \pi$. The map $g:x+M\mapsto Tx$ seems to be what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is clear that $M$ is a closed subset of $\ell_p$; this implies that $\ell_p/M$ is well defined as a Banach space with norm
  $$\|x+M\|=d(x,M)=\inf\{\|x-y\|_p:y\in\mathbb{M}\}$$
  Let $\pi:\ell_p\rightarrow\ell_p/M$ be the quotient map $x\mapsto x+M$.
- The operator $T:\ell_p\rightarrow\ell_p$ given by
  $$(Tx)(n)=x(2n),\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
  is  bounded:
  $$\|Tx\|^p_p=\sum_n|x(2n)|^p\leq \sum_n|x(n)|^p=\|x\|^p_p$$
- It is easy to check that for any $x\in \ell_p$, $\|x+M\|=\|Tx\|_p$, for if $y\in M$
  $$\|x-y\|^p_p=\sum_n|x(2n)|^p+\sum_n|x(2n-1)-y(2n-1)|^p\geq\sum_n|x(2n)|^p_p$$
- Since $Tx=Ty$ whenever $x-y\in M$, and $\pi$ is a projection map, there [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties) a unique map $g:\ell_p/M\rightarrow \ell_p$ such that
  $$ T=g\circ \pi$$
  It is easy to check that $g$ is linear and surjective: $g(x+M)=Tx$. Furthermore
  $$\|g(x+M)\|_p=\|Tx\|_p=\|x+M\|$$

The map $g$ is an isometric isomorphism between $\ell_p/M$ and $\ell_p$.

Comment: Before continuing reading your answer, what do you mean by $x(n,2n)$ in $Tx(n)=x(2n),\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$ : I am confused since I thought $x(n) \in \mathbb{F}$ not $x(n) \in \ell_p$

Comment: Elements of $\ell_p$ are functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{F}$ that are $p$-integrable with respect to the counting measure. $Tx\in\ell_p$ and by $Tx(n)$ I mean the value of the function $Tx:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ at $n$. Maybe a better notation should be $(Tx)(n)$.

Comment: So you mean that the nth component of Tx equals (2n)th component of x?

Comment: Taking infimum on y for $\|x-y\|^p_p\geq\sum_n|x(2n)|^p$, would yield $\|x+M\| \geq \|Tx\|_p$ and not $\|x+M\| = \|Tx\|_p$(?)

Comment: The infimum is achieved when $y(2n-1)=x(2n-1)$ for all $n$, so $\|x+M\|=\|Tx\|_p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is it accessible to learn quickly why "...there exists a unique map..."? The link doesn't prove the claim!

Comment: It is a set theoretic construction and is surprisingly easy to check. Let $X$ be a set and $R$ an equivalence relation in $X$. For any $x\in X$, denote by $R[x]$ the equivalence class of $x$, that is $R[x]=\{y\in x: (x,y)\in R\}$. $X/R$ is the collection of distinct equivalent classes. 
Define the quotient map $\pi:X\rightarrow X/R$ as $x\mapsto R[x]$.

Comment: The quotient map is surjective, and if $(x,y)\in R$, then $R[x]=R[y]$. Suppose $Y$ is another set and that $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function that is constant on each equivalent class, that is, whenever $(x,y)\in R$, $T(x)=T(y)$. Define $g:X/R\rightarrow Y$ as $g(R[x])=T(x)$. This is a well define map, for if $y\in R[x]$, then $T(x)=T(y)$. That is, if $R[x]=R[y]$, then $g(T[x])=g(T[y])$. The function $g$ has the property (almost by design) that $T=g\circ \pi$: for any $x\in X$, $\pi(x)=R[x]$ and $g(\pi(x))=g(R[x])=T(x)$.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is another function $G:X/R\rightarrow Y$ such that $T=G\circ\pi$. Then, for any $x\in X$, $T(x)=G(\pi(x))=G(T[x])$. For any $R^*\in X/R$, we have that $R^*=R[x]$ for some $x\in X$. Thus, $G(R^*)=G(R[x])=T(x)=g(R[x])=g(R^*)$. Therefore, $G=g$.